# How to style HTML to display 2 data cards to a printed page?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an input document of XML data that will resolve nicely into data cards that can be printed 2 to a page (or maybe 4 to a page, or 9 to a page, or something).

What's the best way for me to style the data for them to be printed that way? For example, how can I say "Make this div extend 1/3 of the way down a printed page"?

Comment: I was about to post an answer and realised that you where not using php. or are you? Because if so there is a better way of doing that then css.

Comment: Sadly no PHP involved. How would you do it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML isn't really intended for exact display in that way. Having said that...

If you know the paper size, you can perhaps be clever with the units in a print stylesheet (i.e. using `cm` rather than `px` or `em`). You may even be able to use percentages and not worry about the paper size too much, but **I haven't tested this**. It would also depend on the content, its layout, and how different the paper sizes might be.

An example of using percentages (to force a `<div>` to be 1/3 the page height) would be specifying `height: 33%` in the CSS.

It is also possible to force page breaks in CSS, by specifying [`page-break-after: always`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_print_pageba.asp) (or `page-break-before: always` if that is more convenient).